# MySql Logical Order By

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, logic

I currently have query like this:

```
SELECT 'id', 'clanid', 'name',
       'level', 'exp', 'warwinpercent',
       'warswon', 'warslost', 'warstied',
       'playercount', 'score'
FROM clans
WHERE warswon >= 100
ORDER BY warwinpercent DESC, warswon DESC;
```

Now that works but in the end it isn't as logical as I would hope it could be...

For example.

Let's say there is a row which has 99.5738% war win percent and 208 wars won.
And another which has 100% war win percent and 103 wars won.

I'd want the 99% row to be above the 100% row. Is there any way for me to get this working?

An equation I'd have is:

```
warinpercent = warswon/(warswon+warstied+warlost)*100
order by warwinpercent
if warwinpercent are in a range of 3% then order by warswon between them.
```

Comment: Have you figured out the equation that will order them how you like?

Comment: http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams see update.

Comment: Your ordering is not transitive.

Comment: @lad2025 do you have a MySql example

Comment: Karoly is right. If you have 1000 scores that are all less than 3 % apart, but range from 0% to 100%, then you will end up sorting by number of won games only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using ordering like in **[`How Not To Sort By Average Rating`](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html)**

> **PROBLEM:**
>
> You need some sort of "score" to sort by.
>
> *WRONG SOLUTION #1*: Score = (Positive ratings) - (Negative ratings)
>
> *WRONG SOLUTION #2:* Score = Average rating = (Positive ratings) /
>   (Total ratings)
>
> **CORRECT SOLUTION:** Score = Lower bound of Wilson score confidence
>   interval for a Bernoulli parameter

[image]

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE clans(id INT, name VARCHAR(100), warswon INT, warslost INT);

INSERT INTO clans VALUES (1, 'aaa',  208, 6), (2, 'bbb', 103, 0);

SELECT id, name,warswon, warslost,((warswon + 1.9208) / (warswon + warslost) - 
                 1.96 * SQRT((warswon * warslost) / (warswon + warslost) + 0.9604) / 
                          (warswon + warslost)) / (1 + 3.8416 / (warswon + warslost)) 
       AS ci_lower_bound 
FROM clans 
ORDER BY ci_lower_bound DESC;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e91ac/1/0)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═════╦═══════╦══════════╦═══════════╦════════════════════╗
║ id  ║ name  ║ warswon  ║ warslost  ║   ci_lower_bound   ║
╠═════╬═══════╬══════════╬═══════════╬════════════════════╣
║  2  ║ bbb   ║     103  ║        0  ║ 0.9640439675800224 ║
║  1  ║ aaa   ║     208  ║        6  ║ 0.9401908847803808 ║
╚═════╩═══════╩══════════╩═══════════╩════════════════════╝
```