# Sort comments by upvotes-downvotes, make sure ones without votes are displayed above negative

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm fetching comments and sorting them by their score (`upvotes-downvotes`). However if a comment has not been voted on at all, then it has NULL upvotes & downvotes, and so ones that are negative will be displayed first.

Upvotes are `cv_type = 1`, downvotes are `cv_type = 0`.

```
SELECT c_id,c_text,c_date,c_parentid,u_username,
(select sum(IF( cv.cv_type=  '1', 1 ,  0 )) from comment_votes cv where cv_commentid=comments.c_id ) as upvotes,
(select sum(IF( cv.cv_type=  '0', 1 ,  0 )) from comment_votes cv where cv_commentid=comments.c_id ) as downvotes
FROM comments
INNER JOIN users
ON u_id = c_userid
WHERE c_postid = ? AND c_parentid = 0
ORDER BY upvotes-downvotes
DESC LIMIT 100
```

Any way to make sure ones without votes are above ones that are negative?

Comment: Probably related [MYSQL order by like/dislikes and popularity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111209/mysql-order-by-like-dislikes-and-popularity/34111567#34111567). Anyway `Score = (Positive ratings) - (Negative ratings)` is not best idea.

Comment: you can convert `NULL` to 0 in case where upvotes or downvotes are not there..

Comment: @lad2025 true but I'm starting with basic score sum, I'll try to implement something more reliable later to sort as "best" rather than "top" comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `coalesce()` function to replace the `NULL` values with `0`:

```
SELECT c_id, c_text, c_date, c_parentid, u_username,
       coalesce((select sum(cv.cv_type = '1') from comment_votes cv where cv.cv_commentid= c.c_id ), 0) as upvotes,
       coalesce((select sum(cv.cv_type = '0') from comment_votes cv where cv.cv_commentid = c.c_id ), 0) as downvotes
FROM comments c INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON u.u_id = c.c_userid
WHERE c.c_postid = ? AND c.c_parentid = 0
ORDER BY upvotes - downvotes DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Note:  you should use table aliases and qualified column names instead of naming columns in a table with a prefix.  Instead of using `c_parentid`, use `c.parentid`.  Sometimes prefixes on column names are useful, but SQL uses table aliases to identify the table where a column comes from.